# middleware doesn't able to get the route parameter in Laravel

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-middleware

this is my code:
the route:

```
Route::get('lang/change', [LangController::class, 'change'])->name('changeLang');
```

nav.blade.php

```
 <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-6 text-right">
                <strong>Select Language: </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control changeLang">
                    <option value="en" {{ session()->get('locale') == 'en' ? 'selected' : '' }}>English</option>
                    <option value="ar" {{ session()->get('locale') == 'ar' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Arabic</option>
                </select>
        </div>
          @endauth
        </ul>
      </div>

<span class="text-white">{{ auth()->user() !=null ? auth()->user()->name : "Guest" }}</span>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var url = "{{ route('changeLang') }}";

    $(".changeLang").change(function(){
        window.location.href = url + "?lang="+ $(this).val();
    });

</script>
```

this is the middleware: (i have registered it in the kernal with web middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (session()->has('locale')) {
        App::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the parameter you're passing.
All I see is route-url without params

You can check-out this url if you want or just check this block here from laravel documentation

> Occasionally you may need to specify a route parameter that may not
> always be present in the URI. You may do so by placing a ? mark after
> the parameter name. Make sure to give the route's corresponding
> variable a default value:

```
Route::get('/user/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
    return $name;
});

Route::get('/user/{name?}', function ($name = 'John') {
    return $name;
});
```

I assume you're going with the latest version of Laravel as well
Here is the documentation link for routing with parameters
[Go To Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing)

And here is the exact tab where you can find my snippets
[Laravel Params](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is small misunderstanding.

Your route doesnt accept any of the parameters, you are dealing with request.
In you case, the solution should be the next:

```php
    $language = $request->query('lang');
    if (null !== $language) {
        App::setLocale($language);
    }

    return $next($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally solved this,now you can get lang params in middleware

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/



Route::middleware([MyMiddleware::class])->group(function () {
    Route::get('lang/change', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('changeLang');
});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-6 text-right">
    <strong>Select Language: </strong>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control changeLang">
        <option value="en" {{ $_GET['lang'] == 'en' ? 'selected' : '' }}>English</option>
        <option value="ar" {{ $_GET['lang'] == 'ar' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Arabic</option>
    </select>
</div>
{{-- @endauth --}}
</ul>
</div>

{{-- <span class="text-white">{{ auth()->user() !=null ? auth()->user()->name : "Guest" }}</span> --}}

</div>
</nav>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var url = "{{ route('changeLang') }}";

$(".changeLang").change(function(){
window.location.href = url + "?lang="+ $(this).val();
});

</script>
```

MyMiddleware.php

```
     <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // you can use 
        print_r($_GET);

        // or you can use this also 
        print_r($request->query('lang'));

        // or you can use this also 
        print_r($request->all());
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```